# Little line above status bar issue

Tags: ios, swift, statusbar

In my application there was a small line (about 1px white line) above status bar. What could be the problem?

[image]

Comment: This is 8.0. I have this problem only with this app. App is embaded in TabBar

Comment: who puts the blue background onto your screen? what is the size of that? which devices are affected?

Comment: Do you have transparent status bar? Is your blue color part of you main view? Could it be that your main view has a small offset at the top?

Comment: Blue color is in navigationBar

Comment: I saw a green 1px line similar to this just after installing Mixpanel.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the same background color throughout the app, this should help you (put it in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`) :

```
self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor yourColor];
```

Swift:

```
window.backgroundColor = UIColor.yourColor();
```

Comment: No. My background color is grey.

Comment: I meant the same background color for the `UINavigationBar` (didn't make it clear, sorry). I'm thinking the `UIWindow`'s background color "bleeds" under the view you're showing, and that's why you're getting that white line. You might try and plug in that line of code and see if that's the case.